# What's this mystery symbol on a manufactured machine?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering

I hope this is the right place to ask this question; if not I'd really appreciate some tips as to where else I can go for answers.

[image]

The symbol above (apologies for the blurry quality) is on a Chinese/Taiwanese-manufactured piece of testing equipment. It's located on the manufacturer's sticker. I can find absolutely no trace of it elsewhere on the Internet (I've absolutely, positively searched).

Can anybody shed some light as to what this symbol might mean? E.g. an electrical safety certification, a manufacturing standard...?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Says this item is rated for use by a rap singer?   :-)

Comment: company logo? Maida Corp? ( Though I guess its actually a stylized "CMC" )

Comment: I don't have the answer, but this web page shows some qualification certificates for Foshan Analytical Instrument Co that feature this symbol: http://www.fofen.com/EnCompHonor1.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess after a couple minutes of Googling is that this is a `CMC` certification which stands for `China Metrology Certification`.  If you search for that however, the first result points to `China Metrology Accreditation` which has a logo nearly identical to that one.

That first result is at [this link](http://hqts-qai.com/accreditations-certifications/).

The logo you will find looks like this:

[image: image CMA]

I have no idea what these are for.  The corresponding text from that one site includes:

> China Metrology Accreditation (CMA) is a mandatory accreditation system designed to assess the metrology capabilities of testing or calibration laboratories that will test products being sold into the Chinese market.  This accreditation allows HQTS-QAI to issue test reports and certificates bearing the CMA mark, which verifies that the tested products conform to China’s mandatory quality and safety standards.  Test reports bearing the CMA mark are accepted as legal documents in China.

Comment: To find that image, I searched Google images for `china "cmc" certificate`.  Several rows down, there was an image from [this site](http://www.flowmetertransmitter.com/quality.html) which calls out that particular certificate as the `China of Metrology Certification`.  I added `china` to the original search since my first results that included the logo were all Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be related to GB/T 50430-2007, the Chinese "Code for Qualtity management of Engingeering Construction Enterprises". Unfortunately I can't find the full text translated into english, but found reference to the CMC mark [in section 11.5.1](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nPumDgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA63&ots=d_alubKM3b&dq=CMC%20certification%20test%20equipment%20china&pg=PA63#v=onepage&q=CMC%20marking&f=false)